# How to locate a dynamically populated elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I populate my web page dynamically using `jquery`. Then I want to locate those dynamically populated elements, but there is no source code for them. This is weird : I can see those elements on the webpage, they are populated perfectly fine. However  ,  as I click `F12` I can't see any source code, and `jquery` cannot locate them .

This is my full code, if you copy paste it , you will see that the first `jquery` is supposed to catch element with `id=q0` which is visible, but it does not. Click on the test button, and you will see that `jquery` captures element `qX`, but cannot find `q0` which I can see there on the page !

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="system/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>  
<script> 
    function testQ () { 
        // This element is visible on the web page but I cannot locate it. 
        // When I open the source code F12 I cannot see the source code for it. 
        var test = $("#q0").val();  
        alert(test);
        var test2 = $("qX").val();
        alert("This one is visible!");
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){      
        var y = ["q0","q1","q2"];   
        for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) { 
            $("#content").append(
                "<div id=q" + i + ">" + y[i] +  "</div>");
        }
    });
</script>
</head>

<body> 
    <button onclick="testQ();" id="testQ">Test</button>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="qX">t visible!</div>
    </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

How can I locate those dynamically populated elements ?

Thank you

Comment: It seems to be working at least in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3b6r2vj7/)

Comment: a div has no `value` to be retrieved using `val()`...test is flawed, try text() or html()

Comment: Thank you! I should have used `text()`. This is weird. `val()` works with element `qX`, but does not with `q0`. They are identical !

Comment: no it doesn't, you have a hard coded alert showing the same text as `qX`. You need to go to the jQuery API when you run into problems like this first and see if the methods are even appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 $("#content").append('<div id="q' + i + '">' +  y[i] +  "</div>");}
```

Instead of

```
 $("#content").append("<div id=q" + i + ">" +  y[i] +  "</div>");}
```

Comment: +1 for attempt. Eric this is not the problem. The elements are populated perfectly fine either way. The problem is : Once the webpage is loaded, although I can visually see those elements but as I click `F12` there is NO source ! It just says `<div id="content">...</div>`

Comment: Therefore as I click the `test` button, `jquery` cannot locate those dynamically populated elements.

Comment: Have you tried it? Your code will output div id=0 without quotes.

Comment: Also $("qX").val(); isn't a proper selector

Comment: I tried it. Anyway as I press `F12` there is no source code ?

Comment: You generate invalid html

Comment: Sorry, I had two issue. 1) as you said I shoudl have used the single quote 2) I shoudl have used `text()` instead of `val()`

Comment: the quotes aren't actually an issue. Browser will accept unquoted attributes that don't contain spaces or special characters. BUT...it;s not common practice any more

Comment: true but you won't be able to select it as id

Comment: @eric actually you can http://jsfiddle.net/173ken4s/ I'm not discounting your answer , rather pointing out to OP that the  big problem was a bad test

Comment: be amazed in what you'll see in some old legacy sites, used to be fairly common practice not to quote